# Throttling curl in PHP issue

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to throttle my curl requests to keep under the GET request limits set by the server's RESTful API. Essentially, I'm looping through an array of IDs and looking to extract a base_bid to an array. I'm trying to add a delay between each request and have tried using PHP's usleep() function to do so but this only seems to add a delay for the first iteration and not onwards.

I'm using the code below:

```
$test = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($campaigns); $i++) {
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.appnexus.com/campaign?id='.$campaigns[$i]['id'].'');
  $options = array(
     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization:'.$token[1].''
     ));
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $base = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

  //Attempting to throttle curl here
  usleep(5000); 

  curl_close($ch);

  if ($base === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
     $output = 'Status code: '.$info['httpcode'].'';
  } else {
     preg_match('/"base_bid":([0-9\.]+)/', $base ,$bid);
     $test[] = array(
        'id' => $campaigns[$i]['id'],
        'base_bid' => $bid[1]
     );
  }
};
```

Is this how usleep() is meant to be implemented in a loop for curl requests? Any comments would be highly valued!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: try to move `usleep(5000); ` after `curl_close($ch); ` and once try it by putting  after `if` condition ending bracket `}` also last `;` need to remove.

Comment: usleep() takes its argument in microseconds, so you're only asking it for 5ms. Try sleep(5).

Comment: Yup, you're sleeping for 0.0005 of a second each time there, not much of a delay! 5 seconds in usleep equates to 5,000,000 for reference.

Comment: thank you iainn, RefreshCarts. I should read the documentation better next time!